# The issue with the interpretation of a line of math in Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $S$ be the spanning set of $V$ ...

And then I encountered the following couple of statements...

> $S ⊂ V $
>   and $L(S)$ is the smallest subspace containing $S$ so
>   $\implies L(S) ⊂ V. $

Please can anyone explain the logic behind the above statement with explanations as easy as possible.

I encountered this sort of state in a book ... The link has the concerned problem
[The problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SR99pMvqmsemmgNcsLUgR2YvnGeNMuMT/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: What do you mean by "the spanning set of $V$?" Do you mean "a basis?" There's no *unique* spanning set. Also, if $S$ is a set of vectors then "$S\in V$" is false - it should be "$S\subseteq V$." And if $S$ spans $V$ then $L(S)=V$ (trivially).

Comment: Sorry got it edited

Comment: Second time: What do you mean by "the spanning set of $V$?" Do you mean "a basis?" There's no *unique* spanning set. ... And if $S$ spans $V$ then $L(S)=V$ (trivially).

Comment: If I am unable to explain the situation... I am attaching a link to the concerned problem with the part highlighted... Please explain me